# How to verify Google OAuth session_state parameter returned to the redirect URI

Tags: google-oauth

I am currently working on integrating Google OAuth and need to verify if the user created a new session or re-using their existing session. Unfortunately the "amr" inside the id_token seems to be hard-coded as always *rba*. Due to this reason, i am investigating if session_state can be validated or verified for a new session establishment.

**Specification**
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0-16.html#rfc.section.4.1

I was able to confirm that session_state is newly generated for re-established sessions. However, since the session_state is not inside the id_token, there is no means to verify its authenticity.

As per the spec, the session_state is calculated using

> var ss = CryptoJS.SHA256(client_id + ' ' + e.origin + ' ' +
>         opbs + [' ' + salt]) [+ "." + salt];

In that case, can someone point me how to get the opbs or are there better mechanisms to verify the new session establishment in Google OAuth?